# I can't remember the title of this manga. I read only the first chapter

Tags: yakuza-girl

Basically there is this male student in high school. Waking up and I'm pretty sure he is dazed and unsure where he is. But then a female student with a katana sword walks in and sits down. He sees her, she ignores him. She has long hair and glasses and is very calm, showing a serious, no emotional face. Everyone in the class seems to be having a blast chatting it up. And then as soon as the bell rings for class to begin. Every student starts killing one another. The girl with the katana doing the most work, decapitating students and what not. The male character who woke up is freaking out and hiding and doesn't know what is going on. The girl with the katana comes close to killing him but I believe she spares him and that's the first chapter.

Answer (score 3):

Yakuza girl

> Senguu Fumihiro is a young boy that made a promise to his dying grandmother to find a good wife for himself. With this intention he enrolls in a prestigious school but on the first day his world turns upside down when all the students begin to kill each other and one of them even turns into a monster. He is saved by a girl named "Akari", sent to protect him by one of the factions that rule the school.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like blood c to me, if the girl mainly wears red and black with rounded glasses as well as long black hair in pig  tails then yes it is Blood c.

Comment: nope. I checked, not the one. The main character is a guy who is very freaked out due to the fact that every one is being killed right in front of him.